problem with error module vercel/turbopack
Hello my problem is this error.
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/helpers/use-websocket.js:86:8
Module not found: Can't resolve '@vercel/turbopack-ecmascript-runtime/dev/client/hmr-client.ts'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js
./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-call-server.js
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-loader/action-client-wrapper.js
./src/actions/register.ts
./components/auth/register-form.tsx
./src/pages/auth/register/index.tsx`

I can try create auth. I think problem we find in register.ts or db.ts. I dont know.
this is my github repository with code. https://github.com/ThomasTomanec/portfolio-website
I try turbopack when I add to package.json in start:next dev --trubo.
My error is solved but appered a new error, bcs turbo vercel working only with browser client and prisma database need server client.
